# C++ Program to connect with MySQL

Tags: c++, mysql, sql, database, database-connection

I am new to C++ (although I have some experience with C) and MySQL and I am trying to make a program that reads a database from MySQL, I have been following this [tutorial](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-apps-windows-visual-studio.html) but I get an error when I try to 'build' the solution. (I am using Visual C++ 2008 just like they do in the tutorial.

```
Compiling...
test2.cpp
c:\users\rafael\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\test2\test2\test2.cpp(43) : warning C4244: 'initializing' : conversion from 'my_ulonglong' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data
Compiling manifest to resources...
Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Resource Compiler Version 6.0.5724.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
Linking...
test2.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_close@4 referenced in function _main
test2.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_fetch_row@4 referenced in function _main
test2.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_num_rows@4 referenced in function _main
test2.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_store_result@4 referenced in function _main
test2.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_query@8 referenced in function _main
test2.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_real_connect@32 referenced in function _main
test2.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_init@4 referenced in function _main
C:\Users\*****\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\test2\Debug\test2.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 7 unresolved externals
```

I followed the tutorial and I cannot figure out what's going on, I guess it's something to do with the linkers, but I do not know what could I do.

This is the code I am using ([source](http://www.nitecon.com/tutorials-articles/develop/cpp/c-mysql-beginner-tutorial/)):

> ```
> #include "stdafx.h"
> #include "my_global.h" // Include this file first to avoid problems
> #include "mysql.h" // MySQL Include File
> #define SERVER "localhost"
> #define USER "root"
> #define PASSWORD "********"
> #define DATABASE "test"
>
>
> int main()
> {
>     MYSQL *connect; // Create a pointer to the MySQL instance
>     connect=mysql_init(NULL); // Initialise the instance
>     /* This If is irrelevant and you don't need to show it. I kept it in for Fault Testing.*/
>     if(!connect)    /* If instance didn't initialize say so and exit with fault.*/
>     {
>         fprintf(stderr,"MySQL Initialization Failed");
>         return 1;
>     }
>     /* Now we will actually connect to the specific database.*/
>
>     connect=mysql_real_connect(connect,SERVER,USER,PASSWORD,DATABASE,0,NULL,0);
>     /* Following if statements are unneeded too, but it's worth it to show on your
>     first app, so that if your database is empty or the query didn't return anything it
>     will at least let you know that the connection to the mysql server was established. */
>
>     if(connect){
>         printf("Connection Succeeded\n");
>     }
>     else{
>         printf("Connection Failed!\n");
>     }
>     MYSQL_RES *res_set; /* Create a pointer to recieve the return value.*/
>     MYSQL_ROW row;  /* Assign variable for rows. */
>     mysql_query(connect,"SELECT * FROM TABLE");
>     /* Send a query to the database. */
>     unsigned int i = 0; /* Create a counter for the rows */
>
>     res_set = mysql_store_result(connect); /* Receive the result and store it in res_set */
>
>     unsigned int numrows = mysql_num_rows(res_set); /* Create the count to print all rows */
>
>     /* This while is to print all rows and not just the first row found, */
>
>     while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res_set)) != NULL){
>         printf("%s\n",row[i] != NULL ?
>         row[i] : "NULL"); /* Print the row data */
>     }
>     mysql_close(connect);   /* Close and shutdown */
>     return 0;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it totally is a linker problem: it is almost surely missing the mysql library. In the project settings you should add the name (and the path) of the .lib you intend to use.